# How to forward tweets to Facebook with normal (no t.co) links?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have Twitter set up to post all my tweets to a Facebook page, however, all links display really ugly on FB as they are t.co links. Is there a way to re-post to FB with normal, non-wrapped links?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to fix this via Twitter or Facebook, since the method you're using is just a simple API connection between the two competing social networks.

There are, however, third party applications that separately handle posting to each service, such as [Buffer](https://buffer.com/) or [HootSuite](https://hootsuite.com/). I use the Plume Android app with reasonable, but not perfect, results.